# How can I create a vector of characters from multiple columns?

Tags: database, r, loops

Currently, I am trying to go through a select few columns of a database. The columns contain part numbers and some part names need to be removed before put into a vector. I am able to do this for one column using the following loop. However, I want to be able to go through all the columns I want without having to copy the loop for each column.

```
Ordered = NULL

for (i in x1$V4) {
   if (i != as.character("PartX")) #if statement of i is not equal to PartX
   Ordered[i] <- i #puts i in new vector
}

z=data.frame(table(Ordered))
```

I want to be able to create a table for all of the part numbers using `table`. I tried to do this through `apply` but didn't work well. I know this code works I just need to expand it over multiple columns.

This is what my dataset currently looks like.

```
#   V4   V5    V6    V7    V8
# PartA PartE PartC PartX PartX
# PartC PartX PartX PartX PartX
# PartF PartB PartE PartD PartA
# PartE PartA PartC PartX PartX
# PartA PartE PartD PartX PartX
# PartB PartA PartC PartF PartX
```

This is what I want my newest vector/dataset to end up like.

```
#   V1
# PartA
# PartC
# PartF
# PartE
# PartA
# PartB
# PartE
# PartB
# PartA
# PartE
# PartA
# PartC
# PartE
# PartC
# PartD
# PartC
# PartD
# PartF
# PartA
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please supply some sample data, e.g., using `dput` in order to make this [a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: The for-loop is almost certainly not the best way to do this in R, but as Thomas said we need to see an example of the data you are working with.

Comment: Hi Thomas and lsta! I updated it to add what kind of table I have and what I am looking for. I hope this is better! Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This will count all the parts (excluding PartX, or at least, returning 0 for that one, but really, you could just leave it in).  This is using a version of `x1` with 5 columns and 6 potential parts including "PartX":

```
do.call(cbind, lapply(x1, function(col) table(col[col != "PartX"])))

#       V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
# PartA  1  0  2  1  1
# PartB  2  2  2  1  0
# PartC  1  3  3  3  1
# PartD  3  0  1  1  3
# PartE  0  4  0  4  5
# PartX  0  0  0  0  0
```

We used this as an input:

```
#       V1    V2    V3    V4    V5
# 1  PartB PartB PartX PartC PartE
# 2  PartC PartB PartB PartD PartD
# 3  PartD PartE PartD PartC PartE
# 4  PartX PartC PartA PartB PartD
# 5  PartB PartE PartB PartE PartD
# 6  PartX PartC PartC PartE PartE
# 7  PartX PartE PartA PartE PartA
# 8  PartD PartX PartC PartA PartC
# 9  PartD PartC PartX PartE PartE
# 10 PartA PartE PartC PartC PartE
```

Which was generated by:

```
set.seed(1)
vals <- c(paste0("Part", LETTERS[1:5]), "PartX")
x1 <- setNames(
  as.data.frame(
    replicate(5, factor(sample(vals, 10, r=T), levels=vals), simplify=F)
  ), 
  paste0("V", 1:5)
)
```